# Delay the call to the delegate method - mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapview

Whenever the user scrolls map or zooms in/out, this method gets called instantaneously. I want to delay the call to this method by say 2 secs. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement that method like this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSNumber *animatedNumber = [NSNumber numberWithBool:animated];
    NSArray *args = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:mapView,
                                                     animatedNumber,nil];

    [self performSelector:@selector(delayedMapViewRegionDidChangeAnimated:)
          withObject:args
          afterDelay:2.0f];

    [args release];
}
```

Then, somewhere in the same class:

```
-(void)delayedMapViewRegionDidChangeAnimated:(NSArray *)args
{
  MKMapView *mapView = [args objectAtIndex:0];
  BOOL animated = [[args objectAtIndex:1] boolValue];

  // do what you would have done in mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated: here
}
```

Of course, if you don't need one of those arguments (either `mapView` or `animated`), you could make this considerably simpler by only passing the one you did need.

If you can't just edit the code for your `MKMapViewDelegate`, perhaps you could do something similar with method swizzling, although then you're getting *really* hacky.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a delayed message with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` or one of its related methods.